# Python - Automatizar o preenchimento do nome das colunas para diversos relatórios diferentes

Tags: python

estou criando um programa para realizar a leitura de um arquivo txt que contém mais ou menos a seguinte estrutura:

```
|R_0|006|0|||01092021|30092021|EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA|00000000000000|XX|0000000||00|0|
|R_1|0|
|R_10|0|0|0||
|R_11|0|0|0|0|0|
|R_40|00000000000000|EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA|00000000000000|XX||0000000|||
|R_50|00000000000001|EMPRESA EXEMPLO 2 LTDA|1058|00000000000000|||0000000||XXXXXXXX|0||XXXXXX|
```

Esse arquivo ao todo tem aproximadamente 250 "registros" diferentes e cada campo está separado por meio de pipes "|", onde o nome de cada registro está no primeiro campo de cada linha, e cada registro possui uma quantidade variada de colunas.

Nesse caso, eu preciso de ajuda com os seguintes pontos:

1. Está correto o entendimento em declarar o nome das colunas de cada registro em listas individuais para cada registro? Se não, existe alguma outra forma mais eficaz?
2. Por meio da variável reg, eu gostaria de acessar o nome das colunas correspondentes a esse registro e iniciar um novo loop para extrair o valor dos campos de cada coluna.

A ideia é evitar utilizar o IF diversas vezes para cada registro e automatizar esse código.

O meu código possui mais ou menos a seguinte estrutura, considerando a extração dos campos apenas do primeiro registro (R_10):

```
import pandas as pd

nome_coluna = ['REG', 'COD_VER', 'COD_FIN', 'DT_INI', 'DT_FIN', 'NOME', 'CNPJ', 'CPF', 'UF', 'IE', 'COD_MUN', 'IM', 'SUFRAMA', 'IND_PERFIL', 'IND_ATIV']

data_registro = []

file = open('Arquivo exemplo.txt', 'r', encoding='Latin-1')

for a in file:
    data = a.split("|")
    reg = data[1]

    if reg == 'R_0':
        data_reg_temp = {}
            
        for b, c in enumerate(nome_coluna):
            d = b+1
            var_campo = data[d]
            data_reg_temp[c] = var_campo

        data_registro.append(data_reg_temp)
                 
    else: 
        if reg == "9999":   
            break
        else:
            pass

df = pd.DataFrame(data_registro)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa tudo bem ?
então respondendo suas perguntas

1. Está correto o entendimento em declarar o nome das colunas de cada registro em listas individuais para cada registro? Se não, existe alguma outra forma mais eficaz?

> Está correto desde que o a lista seja simétrica a quantidade de
> colunas ou menor, caso seu arquivo possua mais quebras do que o
> tamanho da lista de colunas você terá  exceção de indexOutBound

2. Por meio da variável reg, eu gostaria de acessar o nome das colunas correspondentes a esse registro e iniciar um novo loop para extrair o valor dos campos de cada coluna.

> é possível fazer isso utilizando o metodo get do dicionario para
> extrair a coluna que você deseja evitando o uso de ifs amenos que
> tenha uma regra muito especifica para algum registro ai será
> necessario. Ou como você está utilizando Pandas no final é possivel
> utilizar o meotodo Loc e iloc para pegar um registro e trabalhar com o
> seu dado

Abaixo tem um exemplo de código utilizando as informações que você disponiblizou

```py
import pandas as pd

nome_coluna = ['REG', 'COD_VER', 'COD_FIN', 'DT_INI', 'DT_FIN', 'NOME', 'CNPJ', 'CPF', 'UF', 'IE', 'COD_MUN', 'IM', 'SUFRAMA', 'IND_PERFIL', 'IND_ATIV']
data_registro = {}
file =  [
"|R_0|006|0|||01092021|30092021|EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA|00000000000000|XX|0000000||00|0|",
"|R_1|0|",
"|R_10|0|0|0||",
"|R_11|0|0|0|0|0|",
"|R_40|00000000000000|EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA|00000000000000|XX||0000000|||",
"|R_50|00000000000001|EMPRESA EXEMPLO 2 LTDA|1058|00000000000000|||0000000||XXXXXXXX|0||XXXXXX|",
]
REG_SEARCH = 'R_0'
for a in file:
    data = a.split("|")
    data = data[1:]
    reg = data[1]

    if reg == "9999":
      break

    data_reg_temp = {}
    for b, c in enumerate(data):
        if b > len(nome_coluna)-1:
          print("dataValue: ",c)
          break
        var_campo = data[b]
        data_reg_temp[nome_coluna[b].strip()] = var_campo.strip()
    
    #Utilizando o dict.get() para pegar a informação do dicionario
    data_registro[reg]= data_reg_temp
    for key,value in data_registro.get(reg,{}).items():
      print(key,value)
      #OUTPUT
      #REG R_0
      #COD_VER 006
      #COD_FIN 0
      #DT_INI 
      #DT_FIN 
      #NOME 01092021
      #CNPJ 30092021
      #CPF EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA
      #UF 00000000000000
      #IE XX
      #COD_MUN 0000000

df = pd.DataFrame([data_registro[d] for d in data_registro])
print(df.head())
print(df.loc[df['REG'] == REG_SEARCH].head())

#OUTPUT
#     REG         COD_VER               COD_FIN  ... SUFRAMA IND_PERFIL IND_ATIV
# 0   R_0             006                     0  ...      00          0         
# 1   R_1               0                        ...     NaN        NaN      NaN
# 2  R_10               0                     0  ...     NaN        NaN      NaN
# 3  R_11               0                     0  ...     NaN        NaN      NaN
# 4  R_40  00000000000000  EMPRESA EXEMPLO LTDA  ...     NaN        NaN      NaN
# 
# [5 rows x 15 columns]
#    REG COD_VER COD_FIN DT_INI DT_FIN  ...  COD_MUN IM SUFRAMA IND_PERFIL IND_ATIV
# 0  R_0     006       0                ...  0000000         00          0         
# 
# [1 rows x 15 columns]
```